# Unable to get an alert to launch

Tags: javascript, html, function, var

The directions 
In the index.html and script.js files, add the following:

```
Link your JavaScript file to your HTML file.
Create a function named numberCalculation
    Within the function, create two variables:
        The first variable should be named number1
            Set it to 45
        The second variable should be named number2
            Set it to 78
    Create another variable named multiplyNumbers and set it to number1 times number2
    Create an if statement that checks to see if multiplyNumbers is less than 2000
        If it is, add an alert that says "I wish it was a bigger number"
    If the variable multiplyNumbers is not less than 2000, alert "That's more like it!"
Below the definition of the above function, add a call to it: numberCalculation(). As a result, when the page is loaded, it should produce an alert with one of the above messages.
```

I know its something obvious I just haven't noticed it

*script.js:*

```
function numberCalculation(){
  var number1=45;
  var number2=78;
  var multiplyNumbers= number1*number2;  

  if (multiplyNumbers<2000);{
   alert("I wish it was a bigger number");

   if (multiplyNumbers>2000);
    alert("That's more like it!");
  } 
  numberCalculation();
}
```

I should be getting "That's more like it!" alert but I get none

Comment: You should be getting an error in your dev tools. (F12) Once you fix it, you'll soon come across a second, similar error.

Comment: Suprised if this code actually runs without an issue - you should also remove the `;` that you put in between your `if` conditions and corresponding code blocks

Comment: what happens when it is 2000?

Comment: @epascarello https://i.giphy.com/media/lN9wakZ84b8tn7lUwy/giphy.webp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the numberCalculation() function inside of the definition. Try this:

```
function numberCalculation(){
  var number1=45;
  var number2=78;
  var multiplyNumbers= number1*number2;  

  if (multiplyNumbers<2000) {
   alert("I wish it was a bigger number");
  }

  else if (multiplyNumbers>2000){
   alert("That's more like it!");
  } 
}

numberCalculation();
```

Your syntax inside the function is a little off also.

Comment: I got it thank you! This is my first time doing js seems like I keep making little mistakes like this

Comment: keep going, you'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score -1):

Because of the semicolons `;` in the `if` lines the code you wrote is essentially the following

```
function numberCalculation(){
  var number1=45;
  var number2=78;
  var multiplyNumbers= number1*number2;  

  if (multiplyNumbers<2000);

  alert("I wish it was a bigger number");

  if (multiplyNumbers>2000);

  alert("That's more like it!");

  numberCalculation();
}
```

which equals to

```
function numberCalculation(){
  var number1=45;
  var number2=78;
  var multiplyNumbers= number1*number2;  

  if (multiplyNumbers<2000) {

  }

  alert("I wish it was a bigger number");

  if (multiplyNumbers>2000) {

  }

  alert("That's more like it!");

  numberCalculation();
}
```

and in addition to that, `numberCalculation()` needs to be called from outside of that function, else the function will never get called.

Comment: Why the downvote? Have you ever typed `if (false); { console.log('test') }` into a console?